# How do I generate a random number and have the user guess whether or not a number is even or odd until they get it right?

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, random, while-loop

```
int userInput;

Random randomNumbers = new Random();

numberOne = randomNumbers.nextInt(100);

System.out.print("Enter 0 for even or 1 for odd: ");
userInput = keyboard.nextInt();
label:
while (userInput == 0)
{
    if (userInput % 2 == 0)
        if (numberOne % 2 == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Congratulations!");
            userInput--;
        }
}
while (userInput == 1)
{
    if (userInput % 2 != 0)
        if (numberOne % 2 != 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Congratulations!");
            userInput--;
        }
}
```

When the input equals the number it says congratulations but when the input is incorrect it does not ask the user for another number.

Comment: Seems that most people will guess right in at most two tries.

Comment: There is just **one** condition - is the number odd or is it not! What do you think, how many people would say that the number is odd, when you tell that it isn't right answer?

Comment: Of course, if you generate another random int *after* the answer, that would be another kind of problem - task...

Answer (score 0):

This will work too.

```
    Random randomNumbers = new Random();
    int numberOne = randomNumbers.nextInt(100);

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int userInput;

    do {
        // You can generate a new number if you want.
        // numberOne = randomNumbers.nextInt(100);
        System.out.println("Enter 0 for even or 1 for odd: ");
        userInput = keyboard.nextInt();
    } while((numberOne % 2) != (userInput % 2));

    System.out.println("Congratulations!");
```